# Python | ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Tags: python, matplotlib, stacked-bar-chart

I am using an online example to understand plotting a Cluster chart combined with Stack in Python. But as I run the code, getting an error saying that it cannot be plotted because of shape mismatch. Here is the example code below.

Any help in debugging this would be much appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Sample data in a DataFrame
data = {
    'Category': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'Subcategory': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'],
    'Subsubcategory': ['1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2'],
    'Value1': [10, 15, 8, 12, 6, 10],
    'Value2': [5, 10, 6, 8, 3, 7]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a combined stacked and clustered bar chart with three dimensions
categories = df['Category'].unique()
subcategories = df['Subcategory'].unique()
subsubcategories = df['Subsubcategory'].unique()
num_subcategories = len(subcategories)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, subsubcat in enumerate(subsubcategories):
    bottom = np.zeros(len(categories))
    for j, subcat in enumerate(subcategories):
        subcat_data = df[(df['Subsubcategory'] == subsubcat) & (df['Subcategory'] == subcat)]
        subcat_values = subcat_data[['Value1', 'Value2']].values[0]
        ax.bar(np.arange(len(categories)) + i * (num_subcategories + 1) * 0.2,
               subcat_values,
               0.2,
               bottom=bottom,
               label=f'{subcat}-{subsubcat}')
        bottom += subcat_values

# Customize the chart
ax.set_xlabel('Categories')
ax.set_ylabel('Values')
ax.set_title('Combined Stacked and Clustered Bar Chart')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(categories)) + (num_subcategories - 1) * 0.2)
ax.set_xticklabels(categories)
ax.legend()

# Show the chart
plt.show()
```

Expecting this to plot a clustered & Stack graph. Xaxis=Category, Clustered on Sub Category, Stacked on "SubSubcategory". Value 1 and 2 are measures.

Comment: the parameter `subcat_data` has 2 datapoints and the x values has 3 datapoints. The code needs to make sure that the data is of equal length....